# custom content type with designer workflow

Tags: workflow, designer

I am developing a designer workflow with 3 approvals here is my flow.
Requester will submit his request through Asp.net form.
Request will go first for 1 Approvar for approval.
if he approved then go 2 and its go until all approved.

My requirement is when request go for approval , approvar will see the details of the request and can change the request(only specific approvar) and he will see other approvar comments 
so, for these kind of requirement I am going to create custom content type where I will show the request data and as well as task update according to the approvar response.

Is my understanding correct?
If you have any link or solution/example please share it with me .